# How do I get the previous result in this calorie calculator?

Tags: javascript, html

Basically, I want to get the total calories and insert it to another html file for a Calorie Tracker. The result of the calculator should display the total in a new html file(which is the calorie tracker). I am trying to create a Calorie Tracker but I need the total from the previous calculator to display the total in a new html so that I can create a tracker that would deduct the amounted calories for this person based on the inputs they have in the calculator. Any help would be much appreciated and sorry if the post is mostly long code. Trying to learn html, css, and js and I just started awhile back.

```js
function goToTracker() {
  location.replace('tracker.html')
}
function goHome() {
  location.replace('index.html')
}

document.getElementById('calorie-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'block';
  setTimeout(calculateCalories, 2000);
  e.preventDefault();
});

function calculateCalories(e) {
  const age = document.getElementById('age');
  const gender = document.querySelector('input[name="customRadioInline1"]:checked');
  const weight = document.getElementById('weight');
  const height = document.getElementById('height');
  const activity = document.getElementById('list').value;
  const totalCalories = document.getElementById('total-calories');
  if (age.value === '' || weight.value === '' || height.value === '' || 80 < age.value || age.value < 15) {
    errorMessage('Please make sure the values you entered are correct')
  } else if (gender.id === 'male' && activity === "1") {
    totalCalories.value = 1.2 * (66.5 + (13.75 * parseFloat(weight.value)) + (5.003 * parseFloat(height.value)) - (6.755 * parseFloat(age.value)));
  } else if (gender.id === 'male' && activity === "2") {
    totalCalories.value = 1.375 * (66.5 + (13.75 * parseFloat(weight.value)) + (5.003 * parseFloat(height.value)) - (6.755 * parseFloat(age.value)));
  } else if (gender.id === 'male' && activity === "3") {
    totalCalories.value = 1.55 * (66.5 + (13.75 * parseFloat(weight.value)) + (5.003 * parseFloat(height.value)) - (6.755 * parseFloat(age.value)));
  } else if (gender.id === 'male' && activity === "4") {
    totalCalories.value = 1.725 * (66.5 + (13.75 * parseFloat(weight.value)) + (5.003 * parseFloat(height.value)) - (6.755 * parseFloat(age.value)));
  } else if (gender.id === 'male' && activity === "5") {
    totalCalories.value = 1.9 * (66.5 + (13.75 * parseFloat(weight.value)) + (5.003 * parseFloat(height.value)) - (6.755 * parseFloat(age.value)));
  } else if (gender.id === 'female' && activity === "1") {
    totalCalories.value = 1.2 * (655 + (9.563 * parseFloat(weight.value)) + (1.850 * parseFloat(height.value)) - (4.676 * parseFloat(age.value)));
  } else if (gender.id === 'female' && activity === "2") {
    totalCalories.value = 1.375 * (655 + (9.563 * parseFloat(weight.value)) + (1.850 * parseFloat(height.value)) - (4.676 * parseFloat(age.value)));
  } else if (gender.id === 'female' && activity === "3") {
    totalCalories.value = 1.55 * (655 + (9.563 * parseFloat(weight.value)) + (1.850 * parseFloat(height.value)) - (4.676 * parseFloat(age.value)));
  } else if (gender.id === 'female' && activity === "4") {
    totalCalories.value = 1.725 * (655 + (9.563 * parseFloat(weight.value)) + (1.850 * parseFloat(height.value)) - (4.676 * parseFloat(age.value)));
  } else {
    totalCalories.value = 1.9 * (655 + (9.563 * parseFloat(weight.value)) + (1.850 * parseFloat(height)) - (4.676 * parseFloat(age.value)));
  }
  document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
}

function errorMessage(error) {
  document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
  const errorDiv = document.createElement('div');
  const card = document.querySelector('.card');
  const heading = document.querySelector('.heading');
  errorDiv.className = 'alert alert-danger';
  errorDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(error));
  card.insertBefore(errorDiv, heading);
  setTimeout(clearError, 4000);
}

function clearError() {
  document.querySelector('.alert').remove();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(182, 132, 132);
  font-family: 'Spline Sans', sans-serif;
}

.container-1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 700px;
  margin-right: 700px;
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px rgb(148, 129, 129);
}

.container-2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 700px;
  margin-right: 700px;
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px rgb(148, 129, 129);
}

.row {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.form-group {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.form-group-row {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.total {
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.gohome {}

#loading,
#results {
  display: none;
}

#loading {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Calorie Calculator</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-1">
    <div>
      <div>
        <b><h1 class="header">Calorie Calculator</h1></b>
        <form id="calorie-form">

          <div class="form-group-row">
            <b><label for="age" >Age</label></b>
            <div>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="age" placeholder="Ages 15-80">
            </div>
          </div>

          <fieldset class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <b><legend>Gender</legend></b>
              <div id="form-radio">
                <div>
                  <input type="radio" id="male" name="customRadioInline1" checked="checked">
                  <b><label for="male">Male</label></b>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <input type="radio" id="female" name="customRadioInline1">
                  <b><label for="female">Female</label></b>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>

          <div class="form-group-row">
            <b><label for="weight">Weight</label></b>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="weight" placeholder="In kilograms">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group-row">
            <b><label for="height">Height</label></b>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="height" placeholder="In centimeters">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group-row">
            <b><legend>Activity</legend></b>
            <select id="list">
              <option selected value="1">Sedentary (little or no exercise)</option>
              <option value="2">Lightly active (light exercise/sports 1-3 days/week)</option>
              <option value="3">Moderately active (moderate exercise/sports 3-5 days/week)</option>
              <option value="4">Very active (hard exercise/sports 6-7 days a week)</option>
              <option value="5">Extra active (very hard exercise/sports & physical job or 2x training)</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
          </div>

        </form>

        <div id="loading">
          <img src="./img/Loading.gif" alt="">
        </div>

        <div id="results" class="total">
          <b><h2>Total Calories</h2></b>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="total-calories" disabled>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output 
Please change your description to explain more clearly. Right now it is just a rambling. The code gives console errors too. It sounds to me like you need a database keyed on user

Comment: *"Any help would be much appreciated"*: we are ready to help, but you have not clearly specified what the problem is you have in doing what you described. I see no attempt to pass the result to another HTML file. For instance, the functions `goToTracker` or `goHome` are never called. Did you try? What happened? Moreover, clicking the button, there are errors in your script. Did you debug them?